# Angular calling a promise causes CSS/JS to malfunction

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

If i try to set the path of an Angular app directly, it loads all the elements fine but if I do a check like - calling a promise to fetch user login status and setting the path after that causes the elements CSS/JS to break. Probably doing some setup wrong.

Made a small demo to showcase the problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/ClSPJnJamTrU75NCDUsg

```
app.controller('PluginController', function($scope, $route, $location, auth) {
  $scope.spinner = {};

  $scope.initPlugin = function () {
    $scope.spinner.loading = true;
    const promise = auth.delay(1000);
    promise.then(function(login) {
      $scope.spinner.loading = false;
      $location.path('/login');
    }, function() {
      $scope.spinner.loading = false;
      $location.path('/login');
    })
  }

  //TODO
  // $location.path('/login');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by referencing resources with relative paths. If your CSS is referencing an image, say: `icons/save.png`, that URL gets resolved relative to the page you're on. So if you're on `/login` that becomes `/login/icons/save.png`.

There are several solutions, the easiest I think is just to always make all paths absolute. So `/icons/save.png`.

Comment: What is the URL that it's trying to access vs what it should be?